# Json Parse Appcellerator Titanium

Tags: json, titanium-mobile

I am trying to parse some Json code using the Json.parse function but I am getting Unable to parse Json String.

```
var aString = {"boh":"stuff"}; 
var phrases = JSON.parse(aString);
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Should have been:

```
var aString = '{"boh":"stuff"}'; 
var phrases = JSON.parse(aString);
```